# Tkinter, как спозиционироваться на центр canvas-а?

Tags: python, tkinter

Доброе времени суток, есть фрейм, в него положил canvas, он больше размеров окна поэтому добавил скролбары, всё работает, замечательно. На канвасе, по центру,  я нарисовал оси, вертикальную и горизонтальную.

```
if self.show_cross.get() == True:
    self.canvas.create_line(self.cw/2, 0, self.cw/2, self.ch, dash=(3,2))
    self.canvas.create_line(0, self.ch/2, self.cw, self.ch/2, dash=(3,2))
```

Где self.cw и self.ch - размеры канвы.
Теперь мне нужно спозиционировать canvas, т.е чтобы при старте программы, перекрестие было по центру экрана, т.е что-то типа scroll_to, но не понимаю как это сделать?

Answer (score 1):

Нашел на просторах

```
offset_x = +1 if scroll_x >= 0 else 0
offset_y = +1 if scroll_y >= 0 else 0
self.canvas.xview_moveto(float(scroll_x + offset_x)/new_width)
self.canvas.yview_moveto(float(scroll_y + offset_y)/new_height)
```

Это решение работает даже если canvas меньше размера виджета (то есть scroll_x/y может быть отрицательным).

Comment: Хм... а как получить scroll_x и scroll_y и что есть new_width/new_height?